# Swift open new UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I'm trying to open new `UIViewController` when I click on an item inside `UICollectionView`, but using this code my app crashes and Xcode and simulator restarts so I can't even see where is the problem.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView?.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.imageViewGame.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 2, height: view.frame.width / 2)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "postController", sender: title[indexPath.row])
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "postController" {
            let postController = segue.destination as! PostController

            postController.title = sender as! String

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know from this code why my app crashes? If it's important, I'm not using storyboard.

Comment: You have to write also error message that you are getting. We are not augur.

Comment: 1. what does the debug log says?
2. postController identifier exists?

Comment: I can't see error message, my Xcode crashes every time.

Comment: PostController exists, it's pretty much the same as ViewController.

Comment: @carlos21 I didn't declared postController identifier anywhere else if you ask that?

Comment: @user3593157, I'm gonna post a answer in order to show you a screenshot

Comment: If Xcode crashes this is a bug in Xcode and should be reported to Apple. But your question says your app crashes in which case there will be a crash log. Please post that symbolicated crash log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Make you don't forgot to declare **postController** identifier in your segue

[image]

2. You just can present it modally with:

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
        let postController = PostController()
        postController.title = title[indexPath.row]
        present(postController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboard at all. I had some problems with storyboard in the past so I decided to abandon it as some professionals advised. Now I'm trying to figure out how to do it without storyboard.

Comment: if you're using storyboard, where is definition of your segue?

Comment: I don't have it. I thought it is not required, that it is only for prepare func so it can identify which seque it should perform.

Comment: @user3593157 How can you identify a segue that has not been identified in the first place? Instead of using segues, if you want to show a UIViewController programmatically, use presentViewController or pushViewController methods. Search in SO there are plenty of examples.

Comment: Thank you, I guess it worked, although now I get completely black screen while PostController has things inside, it's not black.

Comment: Post another question and I can help you